# How to access the Resources of Xcode Plugin

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am working on a Xcode plugin which will add some files to the Project which is currently open.
I need to access those files for XcodePlugin bundle but when I try doing that, It is referencing to the Xcode Bundle rather then Xcode Plugin Bundle.

Is there any way to access XcodePlugin bundle resources.

Regards,

Amit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue.
We have to use the following code to access the resources of plugin bundle.

```
NSString *path=  [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.xxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyy"] pathForResource:@"XXXXXXXX" ofType:@"Z"];
```

Hope so it will help anyone working on Plugins and dealing with resource of it.

Answer (score 0):

Altough I have no experience building Xcode plugins i believe you can do what you want with:

```
[NSBundle bundleForClass:[AClassInYourBundle class]]
```

With this you'll have a reference to your bundle and access its resources.